# Why does my volumetric jet material appear so low res?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm trying to make a jet material for my rocket ship but the volume appears low res no matter how much I scale up the voxels.
I also played with the size of the object and that seemed to do nothing as well and when I zoom out it disappears. I'm using eevee to render this scene

any help is appreciated

Here's a link to the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52wkINcVpbE&t=911s

[image]

[image]

Comment: Render Properties > Simplify > Volume Resolution?  Or try to attach your simplified file (Cone+Volume object) https://blend-exchange.com gives code copy-paste into your Q.

Comment: hmm unfortunately the volume resolution didn't change anything

Comment: So provide your file (that I asked before) to let us see what is going on. It is hard to identify your issue from given info. Thanks

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bM8kBRP5tiQJ4ZjuXCQeU9xxb74RB9rI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you for helping me with this i provided a link to the file

Answer (score 2):

For *Cycles* it was enough to change *Mesh to Volum*e modifier *Resolution* > *Voxel Size* to 0.1

[image]

For *Eevee* it is the same, but ...

[image]

... you have to change also *Render Properties > Volumetrics* > **End** to 1000 m or

[image]

... increase **Distribution** to 0.98 and **Tile Size** to 4 px

[image]

Material is fine.

[image]

Comment: thank you it seems to work a lot better!

Comment: Great :) Consider mark answer as Accepted so others can see it from main list. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour You can change it any time. Thank you keep this site organised.